# The method executeScript(selenium web driver) cannot define a global variable for later use?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using the method `executeScript` in selenium web driver, I found a problem:

```
js.executeScript("var b='1'; ");
js.executeScript("alert(b)");
```

After I run above code, I suppose get a alert window with value is `1`, but it says:

```
b is not defined
```

My question is: I defined `b` as a global variable, but why I cannot get it in later?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Defining a variable as

```
var b='1'
```

limits the scope to the execution of the script. Selenium wraps the execution of javascript snippets into their own script so your variable does not survive the end of the script. Try

```
window.b = '1';
```

and then later

```
alert(window.b);
```

to put the variable into global scope.

Comment: Thanks. I also have another problem

Comment: @user1849264 Just ask a new question. And please, if you're satisfied with my answer then accept it.

Comment: Thanks, @Valentin . I also have another problem, I overwrite console.log function and put it into executeScript(), for example,'js.executeScript("console.log = function(txt) {alert('ok');};");', but it failed and exceptions are thrown on this code. I am thinking that if I can overwrite function in executeScript().

Comment: This has been done, one more confuse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863355/can-i-overwrite-a-function-in-method-executescriptprovide-by-selenium-web-dri